# In ms-word. How do I change the order of the pages to be from left to right

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

When you zoom out and the pages get small you can see two or more pages in the same row.

My pages are ordered right to left.

Do you know how can I change their order so that they will be arranged from left to right?

Comment: What language do you want to do it in? What code have you already tried?

Comment: @Redek: I dont remember what I did but I switched "right to left" to "left to right" in the paragraph and some other places and maybe something else and now it's ok :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This sequence is controlled in **Word Options, Advanced, Show document content, Document view:**